I entered USA with Green Card on August 2, 2021
Q1) I entered into USA on Aug 2,2021. When will I be eligible for filing for citizenship….?
Q2) Suppose I go out of USA for (3 months) in May and return in August in a Calender year. Will  that qualify me towards 180 ..?

What has your own research on this revealed so far? See https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Are you applying for naturalization under the 3-year rule (for being married to a US citizen for at least 3 years) or under the 5-year rule?
